# Add all rows from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My data look like this:

```
>df
       Jan Feb March April
    0   4    6   6     8
    1   3    6   8     9
```

I am working with [tslearn](https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#). Based on documentation, the data can be made into tslearn object as

```
from tslearn.utils import to_time_series_dataset
ts = to_time_series_dataset([df.iloc[0],df.iloc[1]])
```

which would be okay if I only had small number of rows. However I have about thousand. I tried to

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    ts = to_time_series_dataset(row)
```

But the 'ts' from this only contain last row of dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
from tslearn.utils import to_time_series_dataset
ts = to_time_series_dataset([i for _,i in df.iterrows()])
```

Or use:

```
from tslearn.utils import to_time_series_dataset, load_timeseries_txt
ts = load_timeseries_txt('filename.txt')
```